# Advice on how to compare a date input value against min/max date ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have set up a jQuery datepicker that accepts a date of birth and would like to use the date selected to output a specific category comparing the inputted date with min and max dates per category. At the moment I'm having problems actually comparing the dates and was hoping I could get some advice. I know right now my problem is because I'm trying to compare a string and a string but I would like to know should I be converting each of the dates to something like a unix value to make the comparison or is there some `Date()` I should be using on each of my `ageLimits`

**JS**

```
var ageLimits = {
    'under10': {
        'minAge': '06-05-2005',
        'maxAge': '07-04-2004'
    },
    'under13': {
        'minAge': '08-04-2003',
        'maxAge': '15-08-2001'
    },
    'under15': {
        'minAge': '16-08-2000',
        'maxAge': '07-12-1999'
    }
}
function getUserDate(val) {

    dateInput = moment( $('#datepicker').val(), 'MM-DD-YYYY');   

    //pass full date to selectAgeCategory
    selectAgeCategory( dateInput.format('MM-DD-YYYY') );

}

function selectAgeCategory(date) {
      console.log(date);

    if( date >= ageLimits.under10.minAge && date <= ageLimits.under10.maxAge ) {
        console.log('Under 10 category');
    } else if ( date >= ageLimits.under13.minAge && date <= ageLimits.under13.maxAge ) {
        console.log('Under 13 category');
    } else if ( date >= ageLimits.under15.minAge && date <= ageLimits.under15.maxAge ) {
        console.log('Under 15 category');
    } else {
        console.log('No category available for this age');
    }    
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qA9NT/5/

Comment: Stop storing and comparing dates as strings

Comment: Hey @ryan yeah I realise thats the problem but what should I do right now to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are already using `moment`.

You can parse the date strings using `moment` and get a native date object from the moment instance using [`toDate`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/). Then you can just compare the native `Date` objects naturally.

The native [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor can already parse some formats so you might not even need to use `moment` for parsing.

*Note that if you are hardcoding the `ageLimits` object you could construct date objects right away rather than storing strings.*

```
var date1 = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate(),
    date2 = moment("12-25-1996", "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate();

if (date1 < date2) console.log('first date is smaller');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A64ae/)

Comment: hey @plalx thanks for this, I've tried updating my fiddle but still have an issue with comparing the input date with my ranges. Could you advise where I may be going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/qA9NT/10/

Comment: @styler Well your date ranges are wrong. For example, the min date for under 10 is for year 2005 while the max ends in 2004.

Comment: thanks for letting me know!! I didn't realise I'd mixed them up :/

Answer (score 1):

Use `Date` objects instead of strings.

You can get the `Date` object using

```
dateInput._d
```

Comment: Hey @Oriol, I'm slightly confused do I need to set each date inside my ageLimits object using Date()?

Comment: Yes, you should convert your ageLimits to a Date object, and compare those with `dateInput._d`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your date criteria is but if it is strictly based on years you can get exact date in the past using following:

```
var yearsAgo=10

var d=new Date();
d.setYear( d.getFullYear() - yearsAgo) ;
```

Won't require any hard coding of your test dates and will always be calculated from today's date

Can then compare date objects directly